# How to add APN in Android (KitKat and above) programmatically

Tags: android, android-settings

I am trying to make app that makes Internet and MMS settings, if the mobile operator does not support automatic settings by sms for the current device. 
As it is restricted to write or read APNs from Android 4.2, if the application is not system. 
I decided to compose and send sms with configuration settings ( or imitate that such is received). 
How to compose such sms with APN configuration settings, that the mobile operators send automatically, when you connect to their network ?
Is that a good decision, or there is a easier way to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed done through SMS, but special kinds. They are called Over-The-Air messages (OTA).

[Read this to know about OTA in depth.](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/tsg_SA/WG3_Security/TSGS3_30_Povoa/Docs/PDF/S3-030534.pdf)

Also, i found a [link](https://www.nowsms.com/doc/submitting-sms-messages/sending-wap-ota-messages) that apparently describes how to send theme OTA SMS.